# Setting up Django on apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

Trying to setup Django on apache on CentOS 6 using mod_wsgi but I'm not sure what I have setup wrong.  I've tried alot of different setup guides but i always get the same error in the apache logs:

```
[Mon Mar 31 19:51:22 2014] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=39608): Target WSGI       script '/opt/django/movies/movies/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Mar 31 19:51:22 2014] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=39608): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/django/movies/movies/wsgi.py
[Mon Mar 31 19:51:22 2014] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Mar 31 19:51:22 2014] [error] [client ::1]   File "/opt/django/movies/movies/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Mar 31 19:51:22 2014] [error] [client ::1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Mar 31 19:51:22 2014] [error] [client ::1] ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/opt/django/movies/movies')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/movies/movies/wsgi.py
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/opt/django/movies"
<Directory /opt/django/movies/movies>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Looks like wsgi is not enabled on your server (I dont even see wsgi in my mods_available folder) - If you just enabled such a mod, did you restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Django installed into the Python installation which mod_wsgi is using is an old version. The django.core.wsgi module didn't always exist.

You should work out what Python installation mod_wsgi is using and update the Django installed. See:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

BTW, do not set DocumentRoot such that your Django project lives under that directory, it is one step towards being a security problem where a slight misconfiguration of your Apache could expose all your source code, including the settings file with its passwords.